# Googlebot robot.txt can't get it right

Tags: wordpress, twitter, googlebot

I'm going over my head with this. Webmaster tools have given me a whole list of blocked things... pretty sure my website is no longer ranking on Google.

My current robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/

#Googlebot
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: *.css
Allow: *.js
```

I have 15 blocked items from Twitter etc. Please help me unblock them.

How do I allow them them all? I have tried a few methods from various questions relating to this but nothing has been working for me.

My errors:

http://cdn-media.hollywood.com/static/fstoolbar/white-top-toolbar.css
    Style Sheet     Temporarily unreachable
http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js
    Script  Blocked
http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js
    Script  Blocked
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/80766389/sharing-buttons/facebook/jetpack-count?callback=WPCOMSharing.update_facebook_count&post_ID%5B%5D=2896&post_ID%5B%5D=2860&post_ID%5B%5D=2797&post_ID%5B%5D=2773&post_ID%5B%5D=2669&post_ID%5B%5D=2654
    Script  Blocked
https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/514618589504999424?callback=__twttr.callbacks.tl_514618589504999424_1&dnt=false&domain=domainn.com&lang=en&suppress_response_codes=true&t=1598112
    Script  Blocked
https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/446737124289556480?callback=__twttr.callbacks.tl_446737124289556480_2&dnt=false&domain=ellenpagedaily.com&lang=en&suppress_response_codes=true&t=1598112
    Script  Blocked
https://syndication.twitter.com/tweets.json?callback=__twttr.callbacks.cb0&ids=614458066814304256&lang=en&new_html=true&suppress_response_codes=true
    Script  Blocked
https://syndication.twitter.com/widgets/video/?callback=__twttr.callbacks.cb1&ids=614445742380482560&lang=en&suppress_response_codes=true
    Script  Blocked
http://secure-us.imrworldwide.com/cgi-bin/m?ci=us-304975h&cg=0&cc=1&si=http%3A//domainn.com/&rp=&ts=compact&rnd=1438301242539
    Image   Blocked
https://syndication.twitter.com/i/jot?l=%7B%22language%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22message%22%3A%22m%3Awithcount%3A%22%2C%22widget_origin%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdomainxx.com%2F%22%2C%22_category_%22%3A%22tfw_client_event%22%2C%22triggered_on%22%3A1438301242541%2C%22dnt%22%3Afalse%2C%22client_version%22%3A%22821d511e7a238d7299d48903dc8c97c6daa84d7b%3A1422053366417%22%2C%22format_version%22%3A1%2C%22event_namespace%22%3A%7B%22client%22%3A%22tfw%22%2C%22page%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22section%22%3A%22follow%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22impression%22%7D%7D
    Image   Blocked
https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/followbutton/info.json?callback=__twttr.setFollowersCountAndFollowing&lang=en&screen_names=EllenPage
    Script  Blocked
https://syndication.twitter.com/i/jot/syndication?l=%7B%22_category_%22%3A%22syndicated_impression%22%2C%22triggered_on%22%3A1438301242548%2C%22dnt%22%3Afalse%2C%22event_namespace%22%3A%7B%22client%22%3A%22tfw%22%2C%22page%22%3A%22tweet%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22impression%22%7D%7D
    Image   Blocked
https://syndication.twitter.com/i/jot/syndication?l=%7B%22_category_%22%3A%22syndicated_impression%22%2C%22triggered_on%22%3A1438301242551%2C%22dnt%22%3Afalse%2C%22event_namespace%22%3A%7B%22client%22%3A%22tfw%22%2C%22page%22%3A%22video%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22impression%22%7D%7D
    Image   Blocked
https://syndication.twitter.com/i/jot
    Resource    Blocked
https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js
    Script  Blocked
http://partner.googleadservices.com/gpt/pubads_impl_68.js
    Script  Blocked

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I apologies for posting in the wrong spot, I'm relatively new here and thought this was the correct area, sorry. I still haven't managed to solve this.